# How to run multiple sites in docker IIS container

Tags: docker, containers, docker-for-windows

I am new to docker and i am trying to bind multiple IP's to a IIS container and run multiple web sites with in that. How do i do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Separate websites by hostname not IP address since IPs inside container will be changed all the time depending on environment

Comment: You're better off using virtual hosts vs using multiple ip's with docker. It's more so how it's intended to be used. Think of docker as a service, not a vm for running a full stack.

Comment: Using the same IP/hostname for all sites within a container might cause issues with SSL bindings.Load balancer needs static IP's to distribute traffic, if IPs keep on changing , how we do manage load distribution ?

Answer (score 1):

This network configuration will make all Containers available on the physical network once we define the Transparent Network below

```
docker network create -d transparent MyTransparentNetwork
```

create a new container using `docker run`

use the line below to add IP address

```
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceIndex 2 –IPAddress 192.168.0.26 -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.0.1
```

To verify that it worked, run ipconfig `ipconfig`